# svcutil service contractor and data contractor

Tags: web-services, wcf, svcutil.exe

I would like to know is it possible to generate **internal service contract classes** and **public data contract classes** for a wcf service using svcutil commandline?

Answer (score 0):

svcutil can be used to extract the public data contract classes that are used in the methods that are exposed by the service.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702581(v=vs.110).aspx

If you need to extract classes that are only used internally in the service you could use a decompiler such as jetbrains dotpeek.